# unable to render MathJax Equation properly while creating PDF through jsPDF

Tags: php, jspdf, mathjax

I've been trying to create PDF documents with equations via jsPDF and [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/).

The equation appears perfectly when displayed in a web browser. However, when it is converted into a PDF file, each character of the equation is displayed on a single line, and the minus (-) sign is not rendered correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
        <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://latex.now.sh/prism/prism.css">

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js" integrity="sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title></title>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="htmlcontent">
        <h1>Math Equation with MathJax</h1>
        <p>1/2 mole of NaCl and 1/2 mole \(MgCl_{2}\)</p>
        <p>Math Equation  \(-x^{2} + y^{3} = 10\)</p>
    </div>
    <button onclick="GenPDF();">Generate PDF</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GenPDF(){
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.fromHTML(document.getElementById('htmlcontent'), 10, 10);
        doc.save('a4.pdf');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is results of Browser and PDF[image: PDF result]

[image: browser result]